# Lightswitch send email after a period of time

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to send an email after 1 hour a particular event for example if a user hasn't completed a job. I have the logic and it works on the updating method

```
if (DateTime.Now >= entity.StartTime.Value.AddMinutes(5) && 
    entity.Status.Description != "Onsite Work Complete" &&
    entity.Project.SendJobDelayEmail == true)
        {
            MailHelper.SendMail(String.Format("{0}\\{1}", templatePath, "SLA.html"), @"myemail", null, String.Format("Job {0} has not been completed yet", entity.JobNo), replacements);
        }
```

How do I need to work away from the saving pipeline for example: If the user is logged off or isn't in that entity.

Comment: are you using an SQL Server datasbase as SQL Agent would be perfect for this task

Comment: sql database i think i need to do something in the middle tier